# Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException : Application deployed on weblogic server

Tags: spring, weblogic, spring-jms

I am facing following exception in my project which is deployed on weblogic server

> Failed to convert property value of type 'javax.naming.Reference' to
>   required type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property
>   'targetConnectionFactory'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'javax.naming.Reference' to required type
>   'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' for property 'targetConnectionFactory':
>   no matching editors or conversion strategy found.

Could anyone please guide me what would be the probable reason behind this exception?

following is part of my dependencies.gradle file

```
provided (
        'javax.jms:jms:1.1',
        'com.ibm.mq:ibm-mq:7.0.19',
        'com.ibm.mq:ibm-mq-jmqi:7.0.19',
    )
```

Comment: Whcih JMS provider you are using? And does the specific provider jar's are in the classpath?

Comment: I am using ibm mq in my project

Comment: DO you have Ibm mq specific jar's in the classpath? like "mq-commonservices" and <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId><artifactId>mq</artifactId> etc

Comment: I have edited my question . I am using gradle not maven